# checking host system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

Tags: linux, autotools, autoconf, libtool

`./configure` gives me the following error upon compilation attempt:

```
loading cache ./config.cache
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

checking target system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

checking build system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether the C compiler (gcc   ) works... yes
checking whether the C compiler (gcc   ) is a cross-compiler... no
checking whether we are using GNU C... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... (cached) gcc -E
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking for ld used by GCC... (cached) /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... (cached) yes
checking for BSD-compatible nm... (cached) /usr/bin/nm -B
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output... (cached) yes
checking for _ prefix in compiled symbols... (cached) no
checking whether ln -s works... (cached) yes
ltconfig: you must specify a host type if you use `--no-verify'
Try `ltconfig --help' for more information.
configure: error: libtool configure failed
```

I tried setting the host var by using

`./configure --host=$[my system]`

but got the same error with the new host name.
I'm still new to using configure and makefiles, but my guess is either I'm entering the wrong host name, or am doing this entirely incorrectly.

Comment: Adjusted the tags, since this looks like a `configure` script from autotools. It is not output from make or the compiler. You should probably add your `configure.ac` and related files to the question.

Comment: Agreed, that looks like a broken `./configure` script and the likely cause is the input `./configure.ac`. While not correct, it isn't uncommon to see `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` as the configured kernel name. `./configure --host=$[my system]` will not work. Word-splitting will occur  The command line will be `--host=$[my` and a second `system]` (unless you are just giving that by way of example and that's not what you are really trying, `$[ ... ]` makes no sense)

Comment: The `./configure` output you show reflects an influence from a previous `configure` run.  If you produced that by running `./configure` without any options then that's very strange.  If you produced it on your own first run of `./configure` in a fresh build tree then that's especially strange.

Comment: It looks like `mv config.cache config.cache.old; ./configure` might help.  At minimum, that should produce different, perhaps more informative output.

Comment: Sorry for not providing all the needed information. Still new to this platform.
This is happening only when compiling gnu greg, and is happening with all versions of the file. 
The error occurs when running ./configure for the first time, and I have not been able to get any errors that are more informative as of yet. 
And @DavidC.Rankin yes that was supposed to be an example for my system's name as one word not literally. Should've been more clear.

Comment: Whoa... the last version of greg I find is `greg-1.4.tar.gz` from 2001 -- 22 years ago (when I was still running Mandrake..) There have been many changes to make and autotools since then. What does `uname -r` output when run in a terminal?

Comment: Again, on the first run of `configure`, there should be no pre-existing `config.cache` and no cached results.  Is the output you present from the *beginning* of a `configure` run? Did you in fact try moving the existing `config.cache` file out of the way, as I suggested?

Comment: Note well that it should not be necessary to specify the `--host` option at all unless you are cross-compiling (which I'm sure you're not), and it could be counterproductive to do so.  If you do specify it, however, then its associated argument should not be a host *name*, but rather [target triplet](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/Specifying-Target-Triplets.html) of the form *arch*-*vendor*-*os*.